# Get friends who visited a certain country from Facebook graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-batch-request

I'm trying to use the Facebook graph api to get a list of friends who have visited a certain country, like the result from the facebook graph search `friends that have been to ..`.

The solution I have found is to get all of their locations using `me/friends?fields=locations.fields(place),picture&limit=5`, and then filter out those who have been to a certain country. The problem with this is that the response time is very long (2s for 5 friends!).

**How can I get a list of friends who have been to a certain country, without having to request all of their locations?**